# How did Nephilim reappear after the flood?

Tags: genesis, flood

We all know that after Noah's flood, all living things on the earth were destroyed including the Nephilim from Genesis 6:4. It is presumed that one of the reasons God destroyed the earth was because of these Nephilim, their offspring, and also the wickedness of that generation except eight people in Noah's family and the  animals and birds in the Ark. However, in Numbers 13:33  the Nephilim reappeared and Israel is terrified of them. So my Question is;  How did the descendants of the Nephilim reappear on the earth if the flood had only left Noah's family who eventually populated the earth?

Comment: The description 'nephilim' forms part of an 'evil report', verse 32. They were lying. There were no nephilim there at all.

Comment: That is an interesting thesis and the start of a +1 answer.

Comment: @ Nigel J. Its an interesting perspective but  Deutoronomy 2:20 -21 and 3:11 shows that there were indeed some descendants of the Nephilim. i.e the Anakim and Zamzummim. Hence i submit that the Israelites were indeed looking at a people who were not "normal" as known at that time.

Comment: Probably in the same manner in which they appeared before the Flood as well; after all, Adam and Eve weren't giants either.

Comment: @Nigel. If the 10 spies did tell lies to the Israelites (triggering with them fear and lacking of faith) why Joshua and Caleb did not counterargument their 'lies'? It seems to me that the major topic of them ways, really,  'Though they live in fortifications and some Nephilim are in their midst, through the power of God they will become bread for our teeth'. It could be very strange that those two faithful men did not grasp the opportunity to show how the other 10 spies did tell mere lies...

Comment: Saro Fedele, That's right.

Comment: The most cogent explanation I have seen is that which suggests that while Noah's genetics were in tact, the wives of one of his sons was not genetically pure. For more background please see:

Is Genesis 6:9 referring to Noah's genetic purity?

Comment: I was introduced to the issue by this guy Rob Skiba. I don't know that I agree with all his stuff but he has some interesting thoughts: youtube.com/watch?v=pby2Vh6AM48

Comment: "We all know that after Noahs flood, all living things on the earth were destroyed" - Do we really 'all' know this?

Comment: @JamesShewey: Well if you want me to be specific, according to the Bible every living creature that walked on the dry earth & was not in the Ark was terminated  Genesis 6:17. Now of course you can split hairs and say the fish and  trees probably never died..However this debate would be another question and not relevant to Nephilim who are neither trees nor fish

Comment: My point is that many in this forum do not ascribe to YEC and/or a global flood and there are numerous very popular and mainstream interpretations that are not YEC/global flood. These interpretations have a *really* obvious answer to the question. While it is certainly OK to ask for the perspective of a specific framework, I think it is at least helpful to acknowledge these interpretations exist and have scholarly merit.

Comment: Related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/13023/4150

Comment: "It is presumed that one of the reasons God destroyed the earth was because of this Nephilim" Why? Genesis says God was angry with man in general, not the *nephilim*. Genesis 6:5 "Then the LORD saw that the wickedness **of man* was great on the earth, and that every intent of the thoughts of his heart was only evil continually."

Comment: A FALSE REPORT THAT TERRORIZED THE ISRAELITES
 The nephilim did not reappear after the flood, in Num.14:36-37 we read that the 10 spies who brought  a bad /evil report. in other words they lied about the reapperance of the nephilim,  died by a plague brought on them direct by God.  Centuries after the deluge Peter inspired by God writes:1 Peter 3:20  "who once were disobedient, when the patience of God kept waiting in the days of Noah, during the construction of the ark, in which a few, that is, eight persons, were brought safely through the water."

Comment: @OzzieNicolas Bad/evil report doesn't necessarily mean their claims are entirely false (Amos 2:9). The real problem with the 10 spies was that they only focused on/exaggerated the negatives of conquering Canaan, i.e. the Nephilim, but didn't focus on the positives such as having God on their side and acquiring the land's vegetation once they were finished. Joshua and Caleb had the latter mindset, thus why they were blessed by God.

Comment: @ AngelusVastator: Only Joshua and Caleb entered the Promised land , the ten men who brought out the  bad report of the land ,died by a scourge before the Lord. " Even those men who brought out the very bad report of the land died by a plague before the Lord."(Numbers14:37) They were actually contemned to death directly by God. Perhaps what we see from a human perspective you may be right , however God that reads our minds and hearts must of known the evil in their hearts and so they died by a plaque direct from God. We should not water down Gods decision.(1 Cor.4:3-5)

Comment: @NigelJ  I think it's more reasonable to regard those ten spies as mistaken, i.e. they saw some men who were relatively huge and considered them as Nephilim because that was the category they had for giants.

Comment: I can't believe so few people know about the Bible are are trying to seriously argue for the existence of this fictional word. There is no such thing as "nephilim". It was an invention of the KJV translators. The original word from the Septuagint is just "giants", and it doesn't even necessarily mean tall people, it can just mean  "great men", which is the context that the word "giants" is used the first time. The word "nephilim" never existed in the Bible besides some English translations.

Comment: @Bibleaddict, I would like to see  more of your research on this assertion that the KJV just made up the word  "Nephilim" who were more likely not giants.

Comment: @Dr.Apell It's easy to research this and find it for yourself, the interlinear Bible and Greek are public information. But to help let's look at one of the most critical verses regarding the so-called "nephilim": Genesis 6:4. Take a look at the original Greek from the Septuagint LXX: https://studybible.info/interlinear/Genesis%206:4 - the word here is "giants", from the Greek word "γίγαντες", which is promounced "gígantes", clearly nothing at all like the fictional word "nephilim". The literal definition is "giant" https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B3%CE%AF%CE%B3%CE%B1%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1%CF%82

Comment: @Dr.Apell It should be also noted that the same word meaning simply "giants" in fake Hebrew (the "hebrew" bible is a forgery, the LXX is the only surviving reliable text), is closer to the word used by KJV, so my statement they totally "invented" it would be inaccurate; instead, they transliterated a fake hebrew word, but even the fake hebrew word still means "giant", not some mythical angel-human hybrid, a misinterpretation of scripture. https://biblehub.com/hebrew/5303.htm

Comment: @Dr.Apell Further, it should be noted that the "sons of God" are the descendants of Adam: human men. Adam was called the "son of God" and so are his descendants. Women are called the "daughters of men", and were not daughters of God according to the Bible. God made Man in his own image and likeness, but woman was made in the image of man. Man was made for the glory of God, but woman was made for the glory of man (1 Cor 11:7). When reading the passage in the context of biblical view of men and women, and the word is just "giants" (very tall people OR simply "great men"), it can be understood.

Answer (score 9):

Great question!

Although, when discussing the Nephilim we are not afforded the luxury of certainty, we still have the capacity of right thinking.

Genesis 6:4 (HCSB)

> The Nephilim were on the earth both in those days and afterward, when the sons of God came to the daughters of mankind, who bore children to them. They were the powerful men of old, the famous men.

Numbers 13:33 (HCSB)

> We even saw the Nephilim there—the descendants of Anak come from the Nephilim! To ourselves we seemed like grasshoppers, and we must have seemed the same to them.”

In order that we might glean understanding, we must not force systematic theology where it is not needed, and even more importantly we must not assume we know something we simply do not.

So by removing all opinion, presuppositions, denominational doctrines, and assumptions, we can ask "what does the text say?".

Pre-flood the Nephilim are described as the children who were bore unto the sons of God who came to the daughters of mankind.

So if Nephilim emerge post-flood, it would be because the sons of God came unto the daughters of mankind and they bore children to them.

Do not become distracted with auxiliary questions, i.e. who are the sons of God? What does Nephilim mean? etc

Your question is simply how can they be pre and post-flood. The answer is in the text. They would have been post-flood in the same manner that they were pre-flood, that is to say, "the sons of God again came to the daughters of mankind who again bore children to them".

I hope this answer serves as a blessing to you.

Comment: Thanks this answer seems good to me . I particularly appreciate your approach and reasoning to  unraveling the mystery of the reappearing Nephilim

Comment: @Dr.Apell, I’m very thankful you found it helpful. I enjoyed your question.

Comment: HCSB is not a legitimate translation of the Bible.w

Answer (score 3):

From the Bible account we may conclude that **the Nephilim existed before the Flood, as well for a time period after that cataclysm**. In fact Genesis 6:4 says: "*In that period* [בַּיָּמִים הָהֵם]*, the Nephilim happened on the earth, and, similarly, in the next one* [וְגַם אַֽחֲרֵי־כֵן]*, namely, all the time in which the sons of the true God introduced themselves to the men’s daughters, who generated them these ones: the Powerful-Ones, who were considered, from a past, unsighted time, the men of renown*" (my provisional translation).

As you see, the two expressions I've quoted by B19 (Codex Leningradensis) imply an important - evidently - happening put on the centre of the discussion. On the basis of the context of this passage we may easily infer that that happening was the Flood. **This was considered an unforgettable temporal divide, so the ancient peoples made difference between 'before' or 'after' the Flood**. For an example, the Assyrian king Asshurbanipal declared (in a commemorative stela of him) he was able to read 'stone inscriptions, written in the epoch before the Flood'.

Correctly, The Companion Bible (Appendix 25) wrote: "*So that 'after that'* [Genesis 6:4]*, that is to say, after the Flood, there was a second irruption of these fallen angels*".

The over 600 Flood's ancients traditions tell us that the ancient people never forgot this cataclysm along with its repercussions on human life. **Some of these same traditions tell us that a second wave of giants appeared after the Deluge**.

Moreover, like I've commented before, if the 10 spies did tell lies to the Israelites (triggering with them fear and lacking of faith) **why Joshua and Caleb did not counterargument their 'lies'?** Why they didn't say to the other 10 spies (before all the congregation of Israel): "What are you saying? Where and when we have seen the Nephlilim? You're lying!"

It seems to me that the major topic of them was, really, 'Though they live in fortifications and some Nephilim are in their midst, through the power of God they will become bread for our teeth'. It could be very strange that those two faithful men did not grasp the opportunity to show how the other 10 spies did tell mere lies..

A last point.
**The Bible** (Num 14:36) **doesn't speak about a false** (שׁקר) **report, but about an undermining, disparaging** (דבה) **report**.

In fact, see, please, the way in which this term is translated, in various translations:
"evil report" (ASV); "bad account" (BBE); "evil words" (Brenton); "bad news" (CEV); "bad report" (ESV); "ill report" (Alter); "discouraging reports" (NAB, NJB).

Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possible approaches to answering this question, and they are based on disproving one of two assumptions in the question, which I will list and provide alternatives to:

**Assumption #1.  The Nephilim from after the flood must have descended from the Nephilim that existed before the flood.**

As noted above by N. Ish, this is not necessarily the case.  Nephilim may have come from post-flood unions of sorts, whether as posited above, by unions between angels and men, or other unions (as per [this discussion](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/83/is-there-an-english-equivalent-for-nephilim-of-genesis-64?noredirect=1&lq=1).)

**Assumption #2 - No Nephilim survived the flood.**

This too is highly debatable.  Especially if Nephilim are understood to be regular humans (i.e. Noah's family) or [aliens from the skies](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/686/were-the-nephilim-in-genesis-6-aliens?noredirect=1&lq=1), there is no reason to assume that they all died out.

The Talmud ([Zevachim 113b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zevachim.113b?lang=bi)) actually suggests that Og, one of these Nephilim/giants actually clung to the Noah's ark and lived through the flood, while other opinions suggest that the flood did not affect the entire world (see [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/30369/what-is-the-textual-basis-for-the-genesis-6-9-flood-being-global?rq=1) as well), and Nephilim survived in the parts of the world that were not affected by the flood.

(Bonus material, courtesy of Nigel J in the comments above:

A third assumption that could be challenged **is that Nephilim existed after the flood at all**.  The only time elsewhere (in the Hebrew Bible) that Nephilim are referred to is in Numbers 13, as part of the testimony of the spies.  As Nigel noted, it is possible that they spies were not entirely honest in reporting what they saw.  Dr. Apell's response follows the standard understanding that Nephilim, Rephaim, and Anakim are from the same family of beings (which is the basis of the report in Numbers above), but can still be challenged by noting that the giants of Canaan/Rephaim were not necessarily literally Nephilim/Anakim.

I could go on and on, but I'll stop here.)

Comment: This answer seems to be a compilation of other answers and comments on the subject. Not that it is unhelpful, but it’s not strictly an answer. This is a discussion or a thought provoking comment perhaps, but I do not think it should be offered as an answer. I appreciate your input nonetheless.

Comment: @n.ish it is actually a number of good answers, organized and explained, without making the post unreadably long... If you feel it should not be an answer, feel free to flag it in that way, and one of the moderators will decide whether or not it should be here.

Comment: I did not wish to be hasty and flag it. It is concise and well rounded. I think it would be nice if you offered an answer as sort of a way to conclude your take in light of the different ways of thinking, but I don’t think it’s necessary, just desirable.

Comment: Re:assumption1 - "I confirm my covenant with you: Never again will all living things be wiped out by the waters of a flood; never again will a flood destroy the earth."  Gen 9:11 NET

Comment: @neville I'm not sure what that verse has to do with my first assumption...

Comment: @רבותמחשבות sorry, to be more specific; assumption-1 uses the term "descendants" and assumption-2 suggests that certain Nephilim survived but Gen 9:11 states "all living things" were "wiped out" which certainly means no descendants could have survived.

Comment: @neville Genesis 9:11 may mean that all living things were wiped out in the area that the flood affected.  For further reading, see the linked question about the possibility of a local flood based on the text of Genesis

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Yes, I read the link, however if Gen 9:11 can be interpreted "...never again will a flood destroy the [localized] land" this makes God a liar, since destructive flooding persists today. So I'm firmly convinced that "...never again will a flood destroy the earth" is a global statement.

Comment: A fourth option is that the Nephilim reappeared in the same manner as they appeared before the flood, and for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

In spite of the fact that God put the demons who produced the Nephilim who lived before the Flood into Tartarus, it was not long after the Flood that the Devil again tried to stop the Messiah by producing more Nephilim. However, it seems the Devil had become aware that demons who participated in making the Nephilim would be imprisoned in Tartarus, so in the second outbreak of Nephilim there were only a limited number of them, and they seemed to be mostly concentrated in Israel, the Promised Land. However, there is evidence that there were also some Nephilim in other parts of the world. The Bible tells us that the Nephilim were the famous men who lived in ancient times (Gen. 6:4). Although many histories and ancient mythologies have been lost, distorted, or exaggerated, there are ancient records and mythologies that claim that “gods” cohabited with women and produced leaders and heroes such as the Greek heroes Perseus and Hercules, who were indeed famous. So even this second outbreak of Nephilim, although more limited in number, could have been widely spread.

That second outbreak of Nephilim occurred shortly after the Flood. We know that because when Abraham entered the land of Canaan, about 400 years after the Flood, “the Canaanite was already in the land” (Gen. 12:6). These “Canaanites” were Nephilim. We know that because, by Genesis 14:5, some of the inhabitants of Canaan were being called “Rephaim,” and the Rephaim were Nephilim, and were descendants of “Rapha.”
After the Exodus, when the Israelites came out of Egypt, Moses sent spies into the Promised Land. The spies encountered Nephilim in the Promised Land and returned to Moses and the Israelites in the wilderness. The spies reported: “And we saw the Nephilim there (the sons of Anak come from the Nephilim), and in our own sight we seemed like grasshoppers, and we seemed that way in their sight” (Num. 13:33 REV). The report of the spies shows they knew what the Nephilim were and that the Nephilim were very large people, even “giants.” Moses told Israel to conquer Canaan and not to be afraid of the Nephilim. Moses said, “Hear, O Israel: you are to cross over the Jordan [River] today, to go in to dispossess nations greater and mightier than you, cities great and fortified up to heaven, a people great and tall, the sons of the Anakim, whom you know, and of whom you have heard it said, ‘Who can stand before the sons of Anak?’” (Deut. 9:1-2 ESV). Thus in Numbers and Deuteronomy Moses referred to the Canaanite nations as being “Anakim,” descendants of Anak, which meant they were Nephilim (Num. 13:33).

Joshua and the Israelites conquered the Promised Land and killed off the Nephilim—except for the ones who lived in the southwest seacoast area bordering the Mediterranean Sea. That area was inhabited by the Philistines, whose capital cities were Gaza, Gath, Ashkelon, Ashdod, and Ekron (Josh. 13:3; 1 Sam. 6:17). “At that time Joshua proceeded to exterminate the Anakim from the hill country—Hebron Debir, Anab—all the hill country of Judah and of Israel. Joshua completely destroyed them with their cities. No Anakim were left in the land of the Israelites, except for some remaining in Gaza, Gath, and Ashdod” (Josh. 11:21-22 HCSB). So the cities that still had Nephilim after Joshua conquered Canaan included the city of Gath, and that is where Goliath, one of the Nephilim, came from.
The Nephilim that Joshua left in the Philistine cities were killed off by David, who had war after war with the Philistines. But whereas Joshua referred to them as “Anakim” because they were descendants of Anak (Josh. 11:22), in other places they are referred to as Rephaites or Rephaim because some of them descended from Rapha (1 Chron. 20:4, 6, 8). We should not be confused about the Nephilim in Israel sometimes being called Anakim and sometimes being called Rephaites or Rephaim because it is likely that descendants of Anak married descendants of Rapha. After all, both Anak and Rapha were Nephilim and lived and had children in the same general area, so in a few generations, some of those children would be both Anakim and Rephaites.
Once we understand that the gene pool of the Canaanites had been corrupted by the Nephilim, a mutant race that was evil and unable to be saved, we can see why God commanded Moses and Joshua to wipe them out, including the children. The baby of a Nephilim could not be trained to be godly any more than a baby rattlesnake could be trained not to have venom. Their behavior is influenced by their genetics.

God allowed the Israelites to marry women from the nations around the Promised Land (Deut. 20:10-15) because they had not been intermixed with Nephilim. But when it came to the nations in the Promised Land, the Israelites were to kill them off (Deut. 7:1; 20:16-18). God said if the Israelites allowed the Canaanites to remain alive, “they will teach you to follow all the detestable things they do in worshiping their gods” (Deut. 20:18 NIV84). God never said a word about Israel being able to convert the Canaanites to being godly, because they could not be. The Devil had Nephilim made to destroy the human race and prevent the Messiah from coming, and God had to save the human race by having the Nephilim killed off. So God was not being unloving when He caused the Flood or told Joshua to kill the inhabitants of Canaan. He was being loving; determined to bring forth the Messiah and save the human race.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that Genesis 6:4 not only explains the "mechanism," if you will, of their first appearance, but also the subsequent "outbreak."

> The Nephilim were on the earth in those days, and also afterward, when
>   the sons of God came in to the daughters of men, and they bore
>   children to them. Those were the mighty men who were of old, men of
>   renown. (Gen. 6:4, NASB)

I don't see any warrant for the proposition that nephilim survived the Flood:

> All flesh that moved on the earth perished, birds and cattle and
>   beasts and every swarming thing that swarms upon the earth, and all
>   mankind; of all that was on the dry land, all in whose nostrils was
>   the breath of the spirit of life, died. (Gen. 7:21-22)

Comment: Nick Uva, I’m trying to see what you’re offering that differs or improves upon my answer..

Comment: Not much except to provide the chapter 7 quote that there were no survivors.

Comment: I've downvoted, as this doesn't *really* attempt to answer the real question being asked: If the Nephilim were all killed in the flood, why do they reappear after it? You don't even acknowledge the verse in Numbers 13.

Comment: @ Mark Edward: The Nephilim did not reappear after the flood, in Num.14:36-37 we read that the 10 spies who brought  a bad /evil report. in other words they lied about the reappearance of the nephilim,  died by a plague brought on them direct by God.  Centuries after the deluge Peter inspired by God writes:1 Peter 3:20  "who once were disobedient, when the patience of God kept waiting in the days of Noah, during the construction of the ark, in which a few, that is, eight persons, were brought safely through the water."

Comment: @OzzieNicolas The bad report was bad not because it was a lie but because it discouraged the people. There are definite references to giants and Anakim in Joshua and 1 Samuel. So there were rephaim present.

Comment: Nick Uva: If God destroyed the nephilim , why would He allow them to appear again?.No doubt they were taller than the Israelites. Ancient Greek skeletons show that the average male was only 162cm, Romans 165cm, 5'5" feet, today the average British male is 175cm. The Israelites most likely were only about 155cm due to the poor died- lack of protein. So a Bristish male  of today would appear to be a giant to them.

Comment: What if 'nephilim' is a different type descriptor then we think?  Such as 'pedophile'.   There could be pedophiles before the flood and after and they all could have been killed by the flood (so as to keep scripture accurate) but then reappear after a time, and it wouldn't take any supernatural event?  Also this wouldn't be  'caused by God'

Answer (score -1):

To answer this question, let's consider Nick's point. "Genesis 6:4 reads as follows: The Nephilim were in the earth in those days, and also after that, when the sons of God came in unto the daughters of men, and they bore children to them; the same were the mighty men that were of old, the men of renown."

The act of the Sons of God did not bring about the giants (Nephilim) but made the "mighty".  That's the Nephilim existed before the fall of Sons.

So then, to understand how they reappeared [or existence of a new generation with similar traits], we should seek to understand how they appeared in the first place from the creation and descendants of Adam...

I don't know or have the answers but I think this would guide us in search for the truth...
My Candid Opinion...

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  This reads more like a comment than an answer.  Please try to use references for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

### Introduction

There are several hypotheticals. Some are mentioned in the other responses, two I didn’t see mentioned yet at all.

1) There was elohim seed in the water animals which were not destroyed by the flood.
2) The daughters in law of Noah had elohim DNA and were therefore nephilim themselves.

I will only be addressing the latter as a potential and will resort to using Bible verses only, so as not to be accused of using extrabiblical sources.

### Cliff Notes Style Background

As a quick background sons of G-d are the elohim of psalm 82 and Job 1&2 and Deu 32:8 LXX & DSS. The Bible mentions that although “angels” do not marry and are not given in marriage Matthew 22:30 in Genesis 3:15 we read

> “And I will put enmity Between you and the woman, And between **your seed** and her seed; He shall bruise you on the head, And you shall bruise him on the heel."”
>   ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭3:15‬ ‭NASB‬

So clearly this speaking serpentine entity had seed and Revelation calls him the Serpent of Old, satan. Satan being a cherub or a seraph depending if you are reading Babylonian or Egyptian origin is identified as having SEED and by seed one understands in essence DNA because that’s what is transferred in a seed, the blue print to the life to be procreated.

Genesis 6:1-4 speaks of the sons of G-d and they clearly copulate with women because they have children. We are going to assume (even if you don’t want to agree) that they are not humans for this explanation. I’m not being dogmatic about this response but I’m sharing some knowledge for what it’s worth.

> “The Nephilim were on the earth in those days, and also afterward, when the **sons of God came in to the daughters of men, and they bore children to them**. Those were the mighty men who were of old, men of renown.”
>   ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭6:4‬ ‭NASB‬‬

There is much more to be said but Jude and 2 Peter describe those that have left their abode are kept in chains. It is for this reason that I don’t have sufficient confidence to believe another son of G-d would repeat Genesis 6:4 especially knowing what these first are enduring for their disobedience.

### Let’s Begin

If we pay attention to the language of those boarding Noah’s ark we will notice that every group is followed with the words “after their kind”

“On the very same day Noah and Shem and Ham and Japheth, the sons of Noah, and Noah's wife and the three wives of his sons with them, entered the ark, they and every beast **after its kind**, and all the cattle **after their kind**, and every creeping thing that creeps on the earth **after its kind**, and every bird **after its kind**, all sorts of birds.”
‭‭Genesis‬ ‭7:13-14 NASB

This passage was already mentioned in Chapter 6 and that phrase “after its kind” is mentioned only after the animals but not after Noah’s family. The implication being that The eight souls are not all of the same kind.

We read that Noah was tamiym, translated as perfect or without blemish undefiled. Genesis 6:9

Noah and his wife being echâd G-d would say the same of both of them. I’m not going to side track on this. Both being undefiled their sons could likewise not have been corrupted with the seed of the elohim. So why couldn’t the Bible add after their kind to Noah’s family? The implication is that the wives of the sons were corrupted and given the verse

> “God looked on the earth, and behold, it was corrupt; for **all flesh had corrupted** their way upon the earth.”
>   ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭6:12‬ ‭NASB‬‬

That would infer that all flesh other than the animals G-d kept undefiled and Noah and his immediate family. But the daughters in law were not included as blood relations to Noah.

### Cursing the Grandson

This is where it gets curious. Noah plants a vine and gets drunk and the Bible drops an “Easter egg” when it uses the phrase “saw the nakedness of his father”

> “Ham, the father of Canaan, **saw the nakedness of his father**, and told his two brothers outside.”
>   ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭9:22‬ ‭NASB‬‬

That is the same phrase used in several other places to describe sexual union but not that Ham united with his father but with his mother as per

> “You shall not **uncover the nakedness** of your father's brother; you shall not approach **his wife**, she is your aunt.”
>   ‭‭Leviticus‬ ‭18:14‬ ‭NASB‬‬

This language is highly cryptic and for good reasons but it becomes evident that Noah understood something. Instead of cursing Ham who tried to lay with his own mother Noah curses his grandchild Canaan

> “So he said, "**Cursed be Canaan**; A servant of servants He shall be to his brothers."”
>   ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭9:25‬ ‭NASB‬‬

That is most peculiar. But it seems to make sense in this light. Ham after knowing his nephil wife gave birth to a child and the child had nephil traits. Maybe his wife didn’t outwardly display any phenotypic traits but the child made it perfectly evident that she had nephilim DNA. So any other children he would have with her would very likely also be carriers of nephilim DNA. Seeing he had little to no chance convincing his brothers to share their wives to raise up a house for himself, when his father had become drunk he saw an opportunity in a pure/tamiym mother.

Noah blames the grandchild for Ham’s behavior, he was desperate.

If we follow Canaan’s progeny it has many with nephilim traits.

This is one way that the nephilim seed passed over the flood.

Beside this method there is also the possibility that gnostic witchcraft of the gods was employed for trans human and animal genetic mutants but the key remains, elohim seed had to survive somehow in order that it be used.

### Example of Nephilim after the Flood

Here are three examples of nephilim in the Bible after the flood

> “"Yet it was I who destroyed the Amorite before them, **Though his height was like the height of cedars And he was strong as the oaks**; I even destroyed his fruit above and his root below.”
>   ‭‭Amos‬ ‭2:9‬ ‭NASB‬‬

A mature cedar today grows anywhere from 20’ - 65+’ these are the giants Israel saw when they went spying the land. If they were only 7-9’ tall I don’t think they would have been that scared of them.

> “Now **Ephron** was sitting among the sons of Heth; and Ephron the **Hittite** answered Abraham in the hearing of the sons of Heth; even of all who went in at the gate of his city, saying,”
>   ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭23:10‬ ‭NASB‬‬

The name Ephron meant fawn-like and names generally had meanings back then, descriptive meaning like Esau. Efron was pet human and part goat. The Hittite have a really interesting ancient artifacts of human animal hybrid drawings.

> “Benaiah the son of Jehoiada, the son of a valiant man of Kabzeel, who had done many acts; he slew **two lionlike men of Moab**: also he went down and slew a lion in a pit in a snowy day.”
>   ‭‭1 Chronicles‬ ‭11:22‬ ‭KJV‬‬

That is part human and part lion. And so you don’t confuse things the same verse has two humans, Benaia and his father, the one lion and the two lionlike men.

There are obviously other examples

Comment: I have to say that I am in sixes and nines about what to to make of this answer. My dogmatic proclivities was to reject outrightly the trend of  DNA reasoning but I cannot deny that somehow this aberration of humanoids existed. Therefore I have to reluctantly muse upon your answers and the possibility that you could be on to something here

Comment: Hahaha @Dr.Apell it’s all about the seed in the Bible. I appreciate your comment. Here is a verse that speaks of end times. “And whereas thou sawest iron mixed with miry clay, **they shall mingle themselves with the seed of men**: but they shall not cleave one to another, even as iron is not mixed with clay.”
‭‭Daniel‬ ‭2:43‬ ‭Also consider the name Beast. Whatever mark it has will disqualify a person from salvation. The only qualifier for salvation is a person must be human. The beast will remove human markers and mark them with its own genetic marker. I’m not being dogmatic. Just exploring.

Answer (score -1):

Three words: demon sex rituals.

Canaan, where the Nephilim were concentrated after the Flood, was a hotspot for idolatry. The immorality of Canaanite society gradually grew, reaching its apex right before Joshua's conquest after the Exodus (Genesis 15:13-21).

Shocking that this would attract demons who wish to do nefarious things with humans (1 Corinthians 10:20).